# 3 way binding using firebaseObject opened in input fields

Tags: angularfire

Hi I'm trying to make 3 way binding work on objects opened in input fields (Doesn't have to be Object)

The idea is to open an object in a div with the results of the object inside input fields, and to change the values of that object one would just need to change the data in those fields and the changes would be made to the objects values directly.

Anyone done something like this?

**EDIT**
I have done the simpler guides on firebase.com but for my project there is several fields on the object, I deleted the code I tried with but it was something similar to this.

Controller

```
$scope.loadModel = function($id) {
var rec = $firebaseObject(new Firebase('https://****.firebaseio.com/models/' + $id));


    rec.$loaded().then(function(rec){

        var record = rec;
        $scope.record = record;
        console.log(record.name);
        var child = rec.client.id;


        record.$bindTo($scope, "record").then(function() { 
            console.log($scope.data); 
            $scope.data.foo = "baz";  
            record.set({ foo: "baz" });  
        });



        var obj = $firebaseObject(new Firebase('https://dam-db.firebaseio.com/clients/'+child));
        obj.$loaded().then(function(obj){
            $scope.object = obj;

            console.log(obj.name);
        //return obj;
    })
})
};
```

Html

```
        <div ng-model="record" ng-repeat="record in record">
            <input value="{{record}}"></input>
            </div>
```

Comment: By coding, what have you tried?

Comment: Building a basic app using AngularFire is covered in https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/libraries/angular/quickstart.html . If you've done that and got stuck somewhere, show a minimal reproduction if your problem: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Anyone able to help me?